# AWS S3 GetObjectAsync Hangs/Times Out

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, async-await, freeze

<sub>Note: Answering my own question to help others in the future.</sub>

I'm following the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html) to get a text file from an S3 bucket and it hangs:

```
static async Task ReadObjectDataAsync()
{
    string responseBody = "";
    try
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = keyName
        };
        //THIS NEXT LINE HANGS!!!!
        using (GetObjectResponse response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request)) 
        using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            string title = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"];
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More solutions here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/152

The problem for me I was running this AWS example in a WinForm app.

By default Winform apps' `Main()` methods are **decorated with a Single Threaded Apartment attribute** `[STAThread]`. This causes the Async's to fail.

Either remove the `[STAThread]` attribute or make another `Main()` method without it.